# Testcase Python Request: 405 Error despite not accepting the certificates

Tags: automated-testing, python, test-automation-framework, postman

**Details**

Currently I have the problem that I cannot accept the certificate on our test page. We use Python requests for our test cases and unittest from Python directly. We have also excluded the acceptance of certificates as described below.

I used Python Request in the latest version and Python in the latest version for the query.

I have actually already excluded the following, i.e. the reminder of the certificates on my test page. See code example. But I get a 405 error after I query the request.

```
import requests
import logging
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
import certifi
import urllib3

# Suppress only the single warning from urllib3 needed.
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(category=InsecureRequestWarning)

# Set `verify=False` on `requests.post`.
requests.post(url='https://tomypage.html', data={'bar':'baz'}, verify=False)


url = "https://tomypage.html"
```

Error Message

```
405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://tomypage.html
```

Comment: The error means post is not allowed at that endpoint

Comment: It have nothing to do with certificate

Comment: It's an HTML file so only get would be allowed

Comment: 405 shows that the specific , HTTP Method is not supported for the specified endpoint

Comment: If unsure, a good starting point for investigating HTTP status codes is this site: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status It'd most probably lead you to figuring out that there's something wrong with the HTTP method you're using.

Answer (score 1):

405 shows that the specific HTTP Method is not supported for the specified endpoint.

It have nothing to do with a certificate.

You are using POST method on a .html file which most probably ain't supported.

Change it to `request.get()`

Comment: So instead of URL a Request.get ()

Comment: Do you have a concrete example of this?

Comment: @Mornon https://resttesttest.com/ just change the method to Post ,

Comment: you see that you got 405, Now in that website put the endpoint as https://httpbin.org/post and change the method to get , you will get 405